# Find the angles between the vectors to the nearest hundredth of a radian

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, projective-geometry

Find the angles between the vectors to the nearest hundredth of a radian
$u=2i+j , v=i+2j-k $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we have $$\cos(\phi)=\frac{\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v}}{|\vec{u}||\vec{v}|}$$
this is $$\cos(\phi)=\frac{4}{\sqrt{5}\sqrt{6}}$$
$$\phi \approx 43.09^{\circ}$$
or $$0.75$$ in radians

Comment: A precision of one hundredth of a degree is of course overkill when only one hundredth of a radian is required.

Comment: I don't think it's good to help people who don't make any effort (see the previous question by the same OP : no more effort). It is not good for them.